# MySQL 5.7 AES Decryption result in non-ASCII characters Why and How to fix?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I am using AES-256-CBC function to decrypt the MYSQL stored data, like below

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(dob), @k, @iv) AS CHAR) as dob FROM example;
```

This does the decryption well, however as you can see in the below screenshot it results in many non-ascii key characters on the beginning of the data value?

**Why this happens & how to fix this ?**

[image]

Comment: A) Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=minimal+complete) that demonstrates the issue. (Don't use your real key. Create a new one that's safe to post here).  A) What is the `dob` column data type?

Comment: @SOS its varchar 500 and utf8/utf8_bin character set. This should be pretty straight fwd re-production, entryption is done with the php open_ssl function AES-256-CBC. when decrypting in PHP no issues.

Comment: Provide an example. Complete CREATE TABLE script, with charset/collation table/columns options. Specify charset/collation settings for the database also. A query which encrypts the value and saves it into the table. The query which retrieves this data (provided). Current settings (`show variables where variable_name like '%char%' or variable_name like '%coll%';`). Specify precise MySQL versoin.

Comment: Or create online fiddle which reproduces the issue. Like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0984dbf5d906513ffe0278b96ec7e96c

Comment: A corrupted first block (16 bytes) is for AES/CBC an indication of a wrong IV.

Comment: @Topaco - Good spot! I totally missed that.

Comment: @Topaco As i understand IV can be any 16 bytes is it or does that has to be same IV that used to encrypt the data? In the code it just generate it (Dont seems to store it anywhere but since the decryption of the IV doen in php is using the same it could be same when decrypting)

Comment: Yes, the IV used for decryption must be the _same_ as the one used for encryption. Since the IV is not secret, it is usually concatenated with the ciphertext and can then be stripped off during decryption because of its known length. Note that for security reasons, a randomly generated IV should be used for each encryption so that no key/IV pairs are repeated.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks i think its the case, i see in the code it concatenated. Please add this as the answer i will select it as the correct answer it solved the issue. If you have way of removing the '@iv' from the mysql select add that too. PHP does something like $iv.$encrypted text before saving to the db.